# What are the subsets of $\{\{n\alpha\} \:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ which are dense in $[0,1)$?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory

If $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, we know that
$$A=\{\{n\alpha\} \:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
is dense in $[0,1)$. There are non-trivial subsets of $A$ which are still dense in $[0,1)$? By non-trivial, I mean a subset which is not
$$\{\{kn\alpha\} \:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. For example, is
$$\{\{2^n\alpha\} \:|\: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$
dense in $[0,1)$?

Comment: Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756649/powers-of-10-multiples-of-pi-or-any-irrational-are-dense
see comments and answers

Comment: There's this paper R. C. Buck "Limit points of subsequences" which establishes that for a given sequence almost all its subsequences share all its limit points. It doesn't give a way to validate such subsequence though. Anyway worth reading I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\left\{\{2^n \alpha\} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, **it depends on $\alpha$.** For simplicity, we can assume $0<\alpha<1$, because 
$$\alpha=\left \lfloor \alpha \right \rfloor + \{\alpha\} \Rightarrow
2^n \alpha=2^n \left \lfloor \alpha \right \rfloor + 2^n\{\alpha\} \Rightarrow
\left\{2^n \alpha\right\}=\left\{2^n \{\alpha\}\right\}$$
Also, we can assume $\alpha=\left(0.a_1a_2a_3...\right)_2, a_i\in\{0,1\}$ in base $2$. Then multiplying by $2^n$ simply shifts the bits to the left by $n$ or 
$$\left\{2^n \alpha\right\}=\left(0.a_{n+1}a_{n+2}...\right)_2$$
Now, let's look at the [binary Liouville's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville's_constant)), which is a transcendental number
$$\alpha=\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}$$
and 
$$1=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2=
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(1+\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^k}\right)=
\frac{1}{2} + \sum\limits_{k=2}\frac{1}{2^k}=
\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^k}$$
then
$$\Delta=\left|1-\left\{2^n \alpha\right\} \right|=
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^k} - \left\{2^n\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{k!}}\right\}\right|=
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^k} - \left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{k!-n}}\right\}\right|=\\
\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^k} - \sum\limits_{k!>n}\frac{1}{2^{k!-n}}\right|=...$$
or let's note by $k_0$ the very first of $k$'s such that $k!>n$, then (still base $2$)
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
\text{pos} & 0 & . & 1 & 2 & ... & k_0!-n-1 & k_0!-n & k_0!-n+1 & ... \\ \hline
1 & 0 & \text{,} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & ... \\ \hline
\{2^n\alpha\} & 0 & \text{,} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & ... \\ \hline
\Delta & 0 & \text{,} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & ... \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
and
$$...=\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k_0!-n-1}\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k_0!-n+1}}+...\right|>
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{k_0!-n-1}\frac{1}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^{k_0!-n+1}} \tag{1}$$
Now

- if $k_0!-n=1$, then from $(1) \Rightarrow \Delta > \frac{1}{2^2}$
- if $k_0!-n>1$, then from $(1) \Rightarrow \Delta > \frac{1}{2}$

As a result $\Delta > \frac{1}{2^3}$ (to cover the case when $n=0$ since $\alpha=\left(0.110...\right)_2$). So, $\left\{\{2^n\alpha\} \mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ will never be close enough to $1$ and thus, won't be dense on $[0,1)$ for $\alpha$ - [binary Liouville's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#The_existence_of_Liouville_numbers_(Liouville's_constant)).

Comment: Very interesting example! Maybe this is the only feasible example. I imagine the proof for other values of $\alpha$ to be very difficult.

Comment: The same technique will apply for $\alpha=0.101001000100001...$ and, perhaps, some [other numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162987/existence-of-positive-integers-m-k-such-that-2m-k-alpha-2m-1-for-fix). But indeed, there are many other numbers, like $\alpha=\pi$, not very well known.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro or numbers that [can't be computed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) at all.