# On the Equidistribution Weyl Theorem for $\{2^kx\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

It is well known that the sequence $\{2^k \eta\} \bmod 1$ is uniformly distributed for **almost all**, but not all, irrational $\eta$ in $(0,1)$. If I fix an irrational number $0<x<1$ ($x$ is actually of the following form $x=0.0100100101000000100001\dots$, i.e. many zeros and some ones), is it possible to say something about the distribution of $\{2^k x\}$ in $(0,1)$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980822/what-are-the-subsets-of-n-alpha-n-in-mathbbn-which-are-dense-i/) is an interesting example I found in archives ...

Comment: Thank you @rtybase! Your (old) answer is very interesting, but I don't know about using the density argument for my issue. The key, I think, is that my number is random (in some sense), so I'm expecting a uniform distribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it is uniformly distributed for almost every $x$ but not for every $x$.  What you can say about a particular $x$ will depend on what you know about $x$.  In particular, what is important is the base-$2$ expansion of $x$.

Comment: What do you mean? Why the base-$2$ expansion of $x$?

Comment: $\{2^k x\}$ is obtained by shifting left the base-$2$ expansion $k$ places and removing the integer part.

Comment: Ok, I got it. In my problem I have many more zeros and their position is "random", I don't know if it helps, but thank you for your time!